# How to set email sender email address in React Native?

Tags: react-native, email, mailto

The following are 3 lines of code for opening the email app with the email recipient email address, title and body. Is there a way to to set the email sender email address? Is there a **mailfrom** for setting the sender email address?

```
const emailTo = "support@example.com";
const subject = "Hello";
const message = "How are you!";
Linking.openURL(`mailto:${emailTo}?subject=${subject}&body=${message}`);
```

Comment: How would you know the sender address to set? Usually the user's mail client does.

Comment: The user is logged in, hence I know the email address, and I'd like to make sure the user is using the email they registered to send the email.

Answer (score -1):

The [mailto protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) doesn't provide anything for that.

Comment: [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068.html) may be a better source than some IE specific documentation, given how Microsoft messed with standards and how IE was incompatible with everything.

Comment: How do you know which browser will be used?

Comment: I don't. Do you know we're talking about Microsoft browsers? And you're missing the point. Don't refer to documentation from a company that messed up so many standards around the web when there is an official standard.

Comment: Until a specific browser is mentioned your point is useless.

Comment: Moreover, I didn't find anything for specifying the sender going through the RFC document mentioned.

Comment: Is there a mailfrom for setting the sender email address?

Comment: Nope. The `mailto` protocol opens the default mail application and passes your parameters.